# How can i join many SQL tables with a single ID?

Tags: mysql, join

i have five tables with one links to other tables with ID

```
TableA > ID | name

TableB > aID | cID

TableC > cID | nameC

TableY > aID | zID

TableC > zID | nameZ
```

connected like this

```
TableA ID > (TableB aID > TableB cID) > TableC nameC
TableA ID > (TableB aID > TableY zID) > TableZ nameZ
```

i was using this query for each table when i didn't need to select all of them for each one of them

```
select A.ID, A.name from TableA A
left join TableB B on A.ID = B.aID
inner join TableC C on B.cID = C.cID;

select A.ID, A.name from TableA A
left join TableY Y on A.ID = Y.aID
inner join TableC Z on Z.zID = Z.zID;
```

now i join the two of them into a single query to preform a where clause on them both to get the linked results like this

```
select A.ID, A.name from TableA A

left join TableB B on A.ID = B.aID
inner join TableC C on B.cID = C.cID

left join TableY Y on A.ID = Y.aID
inner join TableC Z on Z.zID = Z.zID

where 
C.nameC = 'nameC1' OR C.nameC = 'nameC2'
and
Z.nameZ = 'nameZ1' OR Z.nameZ = 'nameZ3'
```

but in all the queries all results are repeated a many times specially in the last one but i want to get only a single row with A.ID and A.name if it is in the where clause condition and the order them by the one having the highest matches.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The results are **not** repeated. You may see the same a.id and a.name, but that's because it's referenced multiple times elsewhere in your tree of joins. And your where clause is probably not what you intend it to be (try adding some brackets to explicitly set the precedence of the predicates)